# Cache calculating block offset and index

Tags: caching, cpu-architecture, addressing

I've read several topics about this theme but I could not get the answer. So my question is:

1) How is the block offset calculated?

I want to know not the formula but the concept of it. As I know it is quantity of cases which a block can store the address. For example If there is a block with 8 byte storage and has to store 2 byte addresses. Does its block offset is 2 bit?(So there is 4 cases to store the address (the diagram below might make easier to see what I am saying).

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The block offset is simply calculated as **log<sub>2</sub> cache_line_size**.

The reason is that all system that I know of are byte addressable.  So you need enough bits to index any byte in the block.  Although most systems have a word size that is larger than a single byte, they still support offsets of a single byte gradulatrity, even if that is not the common case.

So for the example you mentioned of an 8-byte block size with 2-byte word, you would still need 3 bits in order to allow accessing any byte.  If you had a system that was not byte addressable then you could use just 2 bits for the block offset.  But in practice all systems that I know of are byte addressable.